# Is there a git GUI for people who don't even know what git is?

Tags: mac, git, gui, version-control, webgui

I have set some of my clients up with Sparkleshare for shared documents, to avoid overly complex solutions like Alfresco etc.  At the moment, accessing old versions of files requires me to get it for them manually through command line/full-featured GUI.

For those who don't know, Sparkleshare appears to the user to be a self-hosted Dropbox except it uses local and remote git repos for file management with automatic push/pull on file change events.  Users can view version history, but no more (actually it's just a list of stylized commit messages).

In an ideal world I'd give my clients a (Mac OS X) GUI that will allow them no other functions than to view a file's log and revert/checkout a particular version.  Sourcetree can do this, but gives the user far too much power to destroy their set up, and the interface is intimidating to the uninitiated.

Does such a thing exist?  I'm expecting it doesn't, but you never know.

EDIT: A webgui would work too, if that exists.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Comment: Related: [How to show history of a single file in Git?](https://superuser.com/q/1356129/87805)

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to only use github, you can use the [github mac interface](http://mac.github.com/)

If you want a interface for git check on the official [git site](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)

Answer (score 1):

There's [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), which shall be rather simple, or [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/). However, if it is simple enough is left to you. But I'd say you cannot forego learning at least the basics.

Comment: If you have to decide between those 2, use SmartGit. SourceTree is unreliable. After working a few month with it I noticed that it does not always display changed files. git status displays them but SourceTree does not. I recommend SmartGit, seems to do the job better. For the answer to the question I would recommend to stick to box.com. It also has a build in revision history and is much easier to learn. Or Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

This gui http://www.git-tower.com/ it's awesome but it's not free.